# Generic extending class AND implements interface in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Say I want a type variable, T, that extends a certain class and implements an interface. Something like:

```
class Foo <T : Bar implements Baz> { ... }
```

What is the syntax for this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Only one upper bound can be specified inside the angle brackets.

Kotlin offers different syntax for generic constraints when there is more than one constraint:

```
class Foo<T>(val t: T) where T : Bar, T : Baz { ... }
```

and for functions:

```
fun <T> f(): Foo where T : Bar, T : Baz { ... }
```

It is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds).

Comment: Is there any way to use it for parametr type of fun, for example, fun foo(arg : ClassType, InterfaceType){}? Without adding type parameter to class

Comment: @Ufkoku, no, there's no way to do it: there's no intersection types in Kotlin, and generic parameters can only be declared explicitly.

Comment: @hotkey I have a function below:```fun <T> wrapClientListener(listener: RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener): T where T : RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener, T : NotificationListenerService```.  I don't care of T's type. But When I call this method, Kotlin asks for the specific type. So how can i call this method?